# Why is my compiler printing the address of void pointer incremented by 1??I am beginner in programming and presently i am learning pointers in c

Tags: c

I started with pointers in C recently and i ran this code on compiler where i found that my compiler was printing the address of void pointer incremented by 1 .Can you please resolve my query??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a =1025;
int *p;
p =&a;
printf("Size of integer is %d bytes\n",sizeof(int));
printf("Address = %d , value = %d\n",p,*p);
//void pointer
void *p0;
p0 = p;
printf("address = %d",p0+1);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnukf.png)

Comment: Because you're adding 1 to the pointer? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Um, you could change the expression to `p0` instead of `p0+1`...